# How to pass parameters in Spring Boot controller class (app is using Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-boot, spring-security

As above, how to pass parameters? I have successfully passed the ID parameter from a previous page in my application to the URI of a page containing a form. I want to then post the content of this form along with the same ID parameter to be saved to my database.

I am using Spring Security in my app which I suspect may be the issue, as the POST method for my form works as intended if I don't try to pass the ID parameter (i.e. sends my form data object to the Service class which then successfully saves the data to the database). However as soon as I add my code which is intended to pass the ID parameter also, I am getting a **HTTP 405** Error ("Request method 'POST' not supported").

URI of my page which contains form = http://localhost:8080/acceptOffer?id=(idvalue)

Form:

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="#" th:action="@{/acceptOffer}"
    th:object="${offer}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal"
    role="form">    

    Note 
    <label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('note')}" th:errors="*{note}"
        class="validation-message"></label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{note}" placeholder="Type Here"
        class="form-control" /> 

    <button type="submit">Accept Offer</button>
</form>
```

Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/acceptOffer?id={id}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView acceptOffer(@Valid Offer offer, @PathVariable String id, BindingResult bindingResult){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    offerService.setId(Integer.valueOf(id));
    offerService.saveOffer(offer);
    modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "Your offer of acceptance has been received");
    modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());     
    modelAndView.setViewName("acceptOffer");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve this problem in the manner originally intended, but I got around the issue by:

- Passing the parameter to my controller's "GET" method via the URI
- Retrieving the parameter in my controller's "GET" method and then
  adding it as an attribute to the HttpSession
- Getting it back as a session attribute in my controller's "POST" method for the form

Not ideal I know, but it works...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a path variable then change controller code to

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/acceptOffer/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView acceptOffer(@Valid Offer offer, @PathVariable String id, BindingResult bindingResult){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    offerService.setId(Integer.valueOf(id));
    offerService.saveOffer(offer);
    modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "Your offer of acceptance has been received");
    modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());     
    modelAndView.setViewName("acceptOffer");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

and Call it like

http://localhost:8080/acceptOffer/id

Comment: So I take it my RequestMapping annotation in my GET method for that form should change from                                                                                         @RequestMapping(value={"/acceptOffer"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)                                                                                            to                                                                                                               @RequestMapping(value={"/acceptOffer/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: mapping should be changed to @RequestMapping(value={"/acceptOffer/{id}"}. Your questions says it;s POST method.did you changed it to GET?

Comment: No I'm now referring to my POST method for that form, because the URI for the page containing the form has changed as per your answer. When I try to follow your answer I now get a "Request method 'GET' not supported" error when I try to navigate to the form. My previous RequestMapping for my GET method (which worked) is as above.

Comment: There is a typo in the above, too late to edit now but it should have started with "I'm now referring to my GET method for that form." Sorry, it's late.

Comment: I have amended the URI and the controller POST method to match your suggestion but can't get your answer working I'm afraid. Can you confirm what the RequestMapping for my controller's GET method for the form page should be please?